# Como usar resultSet en Spring Java

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un crud en java con spring pero al usar el resulSet para obtener los resultados de una consulta con procedimiento almacenado pero no me deja por el jdbcTemplate y necesito obtener los resultados y enviarlos a los setter de un objeto en el momento lo tengo de la siguiente manera agradeceria la ayuda llevo 3 días esto y no lo logro miro la documentacón pero no funciona sale un jdbccall con resulsetextractor y ninguno =(.
Gracias.

```
CConexion datasource = new CConexion();
final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource.getCOnexion());
ResultSet rs;


public List consultarUsuario(String id) {
        List listainformacion = new ArrayList();
        try {
            listainformacion = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("CALL Us_InfoPerfil (?)", id);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            Logger.getLogger(CUsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return listainformacion;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas utilizar `RowMapper`, si quieres tener acceso a `ResultSet`.
Procedimientos por lo general devuelven una sola fila, por lo que debes utilizar `queryForObject` en lugar de `queryForList.`

```java
final JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(this.source);
final String result = jdbc.queryForObject(
    "CALL REPLACE(?, 'Hello', 'Goodbye')",
    new Object[] {"Hello World"},
    new RowMapper<String>() {
        @Override
        public String mapRow(@Nonnull final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getString(1);
        }
    }
);
MatcherAssert.assertThat(result, Matchers.is("Goodbye World"));
```